# Maven exec plugin for clean phase

Tags: maven

I'm using the exec-maven-plugin to execute a custom clean script during the pre-clean phase of the POM life cycle. The purpose of this script is to clean up a bunch of log files and test artifacts that are created during the compile and test phases. This script needs to know the paths to these files, so it is being filtered by the maven-resources-plugin during the initialize phase.

I've found that this was a bad design choice: I can only do `mvn clean` after I've done `mvn initialize`. This is generally not an issue, since you only need to clean after having done something... However, I've started to use the maven-release-plugin, which tries to do `mvn clean deploy`, which fails due to the clean script not being available.

I've thought of the following possible solutions:

1. Use only the maven-clean-plugin
2. Attach the script to a different phase
3. Modify the script so it doesn't need filtering

I don't like either of those, because:

1. I want to use the script for cleaning up, since it allows me to keep the POM file clean (there are a lot of files that I need to remove, and I don't want to have to specify all of them manually to the maven-clean-plugin).
2. Not possible: the test results need to be picked up by Jenkins after testing, so I cannot clean them during the build and test cycle. There are no other phases in the clean cycle that I can bind to.
3. Sort of possible, but in the near future we (might) want to release directly from Jenkins, which only has access to sh (not bash), so I can't use relative paths unless I do the ugly `export PATH=.:$PATH`.

How can I resolve this problem, considering the restrictions I have on the Jenkins server (not under my control)?

Comment: Why do you need a custom script? If you have located all results in target folder it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Not all results end up in the target folder. The build and test tools that we use here have a tendency to leave stuff around all over the source tree. They shouldn't be there, but I can't really control that. Hence, my custom script to clean up the mess afterwards.

Comment: Why not using maven-clean-plugin to clean up other locations as well (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html).

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, there are quite a lot of artifacts that I need to clean up. In the script, I can sort-of-easily find them with `find` and `grep`; specifying all of them in the way you are linking to would result in a long list of includes/excludes in the POM file. I was hoping that I could avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not all results end up in the target folder.

There's your problem :-) The cleanest solution would be to fix that, and then use 1). Alternatively, consider a conditional script. Commit something like this to `src/main/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f target/generated-clean-script ]; then
    sh target/generated-clean-script
fi
```

and then run it unconditionally in `clean`. It'll do nothing on the first run, but then clean up on any build after `initialize` has generated that script.

As a variant of 2), consider not binding it to a phase. Run the script directly when you need to, not through Maven.

Comment: I am very aware of where my problem is :-) Unfortunately, that I cannot change. I need the script bound to the clean phase, because the release plugin will complain if it finds unversioned artifacts, and I don't want to svn:ignore all of them. I like your idea of using the intermediate script.